# Are the continuity property of probabilities always true?

Tags: probability

I'm wodnering the following properties are always true. [image]

It seems obvious when all events are independent but does it ture when they are not independent? I'm trying to prove it but I can't go anywhere. How can it be proved it is true or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $B_n=\cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i^{c}$ the $B_n$ decreases to $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i^{c}$  so the result is true. Independence is not required.

Comment: Thanks! I missed B_n are a decreasing sequence.